# Filter Genserver Termination Logs (translator_inspect_opts?)

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

What is the best way to filter the logging output of a GenServer termination event? It seems like Elixir.Logger allows for :translator_inspect_opts which provide for some configuration here, but I'm not clear on how to handle the following situation:

The default logging output when a Genserver terminates includes the last message received and the state, like so:

```
10:06:00.165 [error] GenServer #PID<0.378.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in 
Module.handle_info/2 path_to_file.ex:30: 
...
Last message: {:DOWN, #Reference<0.1522575658.3956015107.616>, 
:process, #PID<0.295.0>, {:function_clause, [{Module.function, 
:handle_info, [{#Reference<0.1522575658.3968335873.44738>, {:ok, 
#Port<0.84>, #PID<0.363.0>}}]}
State: {%{#Reference<0.1522575658.3956015107.615> => [STATE],   
...
```

In some cases I would like to omit the message and state entirely from the error log, and in some cases I would like to filter out some of the parameters included in each. How can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, it is not possible through `Logger` configuration and it in general looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your willingness to omit logs on some `{:DOWN, _, _, _, _}, state` events hints that you actually want to treat them differently. Just do it—ErlangVM is very friendly.

Implement the following [`GenServer.handle_info/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#c:handle_info/2) in your `GenServer`:

```
@impl
def handle_info({:DOWN, ref, what, pid, reason}, state) do
  ...
end
```

maybe with different clauses and handle different cases differently.

Comment: I hope it's not an xy problem, my generic problem is filtering logs in general from an otp application, and a more specific issue is the logs associated with genserver termination events.

Comment: Why would you want to filter logs from an otp application? How do you expect to analyze issues after some unexpected happened? Logs were invented for this exact purpose. Also, the answer above is answering the question stated in OP. For filtering foreign logs, I _hope_ this is impossible in general.

Comment: I would want to filter the logs if they are exposed to external services, and would only like portions of the output filtered.

Comment: Well, my advise would be: do not do this. There are many reasons for that. Many 3rd-party log analiyzers, like wombat, will become broken. Sooner or later you’ll get into the situation when you need the full logs. Most if not all erlang/elixir applications allow per-app logging configs. Also, if you see many of these `:DOWN`s, it’s a clear sign there is something wrong with your design, like you spawn monitored processes instead of unlinked tasks. Not monitored processes won’t spam _your_ logs.